# Camel continuous sorted read of contents of directory

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to read all files from a certain directory and act upon their body.
There are a lot of files and each minute new files are being added to the directory.

When I start my application and I have a set of files in the directory. They are processed in a sorted order but when new files are being added to the directory they are added to the back of the sorted queue of files that will be processed ?

Is there a way around this ? Is this why Resequencers exists in Camel ? http://camel.apache.org/resequencer.html

Current setup:

```
<camel:endpoint id="store.in" uri="file:${service.in}?readLock=true&amp;recursive=true&amp;moveFailed=${service.error}&amp;sortBy=reverse:file:name" />

<camel:route>
    <camel:from uri="ref:store.in" />
        <camel:resequence>
            <camel:simple>filename</camel:simple>
            <camel:to uri="bean:parser?method=parseStream" />
            <camel:to uri="log:com.foo.store.parsefile?level=INFO" />
            <camel:process ref="storeProcessor" />
        </camel:resequence>
</camel:route>
```

Comment: Interesting finding indeed. You want it act sort of like a priority queue with filename order being the priority. Fair enough. Take a look at this option `eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=true` - even though I have not tried it, it seems to be something that could help you. Maybe you need to lower the maxMessagesPerPoll as well to get the desired result.

Comment: Yeah just grab 1 message at a time, with maxMessagesPerPoll=1, then it will resort when Camel processes the next message.

Comment: eagerMaxMessagesPerPull should be set to false, else the reverse ordering did not work.